# Which solver do Googles OR-Tools Modules for CSP and VRP use?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, vehicle-routing, operations-research, cp-sat

I am currently evaluating googles or-tools and just noticed that it's not really a solver on its own but mainly an interface to other solvers. What I'd like to know is which solvers this framework uses for constraint and routing problems.

I have already looked thoroughly through https://developers.google.com/optimization/,  but only found that

- for linear optimization Google's "in-house, open-source GLOP" is used
- for network flow optimization an own solver seems to be used ("OR-Tools provides several solvers for network flow problems in its graph libraries.")
- for mixed integer programming the open-source programm "COIN OR branch&cut" is used by default (but SCIP, GLPK and Gurobi can be integrated)

But on the CP & VRP info/guide sites there is no indication as to what solver is used for these problems...

Does anyone happen to know which solver is used for CSP / VRP or have you found something I overread?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was answered multiple times on the mailing list/github issues:

- the routing library uses a CP solver with a Local Search implementation on top.  See this [Github issue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/920#issuecomment-435880431)
- The CP-SAT solver uses a lazy clause generation solver on top of an SAT solver. The best description is a presentation from Peter Stuckey called [Search is Dead](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/PPDP2013.pdf). There is also a video on YouTube from the CPAIOR master class. https://youtu.be/lmy1ddn4cyw